# How to upload code to an Arduino Uno using HC08 Bluetooth module

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth

How do you upload code to an Uno from a Mac using the HC08 Bluetooth module? I know I need to use this wiring.
[image: Pins used]

Anyone know?

Comment: you can only upload to Uno over RX/TX and the Arduino must be reset to bootloader